# android print html document on printer in same network

Tags: android, html, printing

im trying to print Html document on printer from my android device which is in same network as printer.

This is sample code im trying to use. Im only able to print raw html on printer.
Can someone help how to wrap that code to print html?

private String ipAdress, htmlContent;
private int port;

```
public PrintBon(String ipAdress,int port, String content) {
    this.htmlContent = content;
    this.ipAdress = ipAdress;
    this.port = port;
}

public void print(){
    try
    {
        Socket sock = new Socket(ipAdress, port);
        PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
    
        //prints raw htmlContent
        oStream.println(htmlContent);
        oStream.println("\n\n\n");
    
        //paper cut
        oStream.write(0x1D);
        oStream.write(86);
        oStream.write(48);
        oStream.write(0);

        oStream.close();
        sock.close();
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you read: [Printing HTML documents](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs)

Comment: i did, but i want to straight print

Comment: Confused by what you mean by print html.